# Using MGSplitViewController Inside Tab

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, tabbar

I have a UISplitViewController inside a tab bar. I know this is not officially supported by Apple, but it did work for iOS 5/6. In iOS 7 I am getting a grey bar at the bottom of the screen similar to the one shown in this post:

[UISplitView with UITabbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980571/uisplitview-with-uitabbar)

I followed the advice and tried the MGSplitViewController. It seemed to work perfectly, I merely changed my type and presto it all came up as expected. A new problem occurs however. The other tabs have stopped rotating. The tab containing the mgsplitview rotates, the others don't.

Has anyone experienced this before? Is there a quick solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

change height -= statusBarHeight;

with

```
if (NSFoundationVersionNumber <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
    height -= statusBarHeight;
}
```

in MGSplitviewController

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me also:

I subclassed UISplitViewController and added the line below to viewDidLoad and that fixed the grey line.

```
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
```