# UITabBarItem invisible in iOS 7 with UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, ios7, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have a little problem easily reproductible with Xcode 6.1.1 :

- Create a new Tabbed application project
- Set the deployment target to iOS 7
- Go into the storyboard and drag and drop a `UISplitViewController`
- Link it to the `UITabBarController`
- Edit the new Tab Bar Item, set an image and set its name

Now run the project in the simulator (iPhone) for iOS 7 and iOS 8. The Tab bar item is invisible in iOS 7 whereas its visible in iOS 8...

[image: This is on iOS 8]
[image: This is on iOS 7]

Any thoughts to make it visible?

PS: I've already checked [Issue with Split View Controller with UITabbarController in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19935997/issue-with-split-view-controller-with-uitabbarcontroller-in-ios7) and [UISplitView with UITabbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980571/uisplitview-with-uitabbar) but none is about the invisible item...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UISplitViewController doesn't exist on iPhone ios7 ...

if you still would like to use it as root controller, check this
http://op183.github.io/MasterDetailDemo/

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let barItems: [UITabBarItem] = tabBar.items as [UITabBarItem]
        for bar in barItems {
            println(bar.selectedImage)
            println(bar.title)
        }
    }
```

and the result is ....

```
<UIImage: 0x7a742ca0>
Optional("First")
<UIImage: 0x7a744800>
Optional("Second")
nil
nil
```

as a workaround try set the right values there

```
if bar.title == nil {
                bar.title = "TITLE"
            }
```

works for me

1) it is hard to say, what is wrong with storyboard, but even if title and images are set to nil, the 'connection' still works

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't take in account my question. The problem is not the display of the splitview (I know how to manage it like a simple navigation on phones) but the display of the tabbar item, like shown on the screenshots. As you can imagine, if I ask it within a tabbar its because it's as constraint I simply cannot work around.

Comment: i added the simple workaround in my answer ... enjoy it

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I had ended with. Even if it's really not nice, I'm amazed that something like that can happen... Anyway, if there's no other workaround...