# Bottom section of UITableView is not clickable

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am banging my head on the wall with this, since i'm new to IOS development. I am pretty sure it is easy to fix this but i just can't find out.

So, since IOS7 there is a wierd gray section at the bottom of my UITableView.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUzLO.jpg

I tried to modify the height of my UITableView's frame. The gray bar disappeared but the section is still not clickable.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/05Q7w.jpg

Can someone please enlighten me on this problem.

Thanks

Comment: that's the footer, it'not a cell. THat's why you can't clicked on that part. Try to set in the interface builder to disable or change the size of the footer.

Comment: @Bejibun, looks like it is not the footer, i customized the footer in the viewForFooterInSection function. It just added a section on top of that gray bar. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i finally figured it out. It was caused by the splitViewController adding that gray bar.

I've added this line in my splitViewController and it works perfectly:

```
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
```

Thanks to this post: [UISplitView with UITabbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980571/uisplitview-with-uitabbar)